# ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

Tags: sql, count, group-by

I am trying show all the different companies for which students work. However only companies where more than four students are employed should be displayed.

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT EMPLOYER, COUNT (STUDENT_ID)
FROM STUDENT
GROUP BY STUDENT_ID
HAVING COUNT (STUDENT_ID) >4;
```

I keep getting this message:

```
ERROR at line 1: 
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
```

I don't get it. I also tried this earlier:

```
SELECT STUDENT.EMPLOYER, COUNT (STUDENT.STUDENT_ID)
FROM STUDENT
GROUP BY STUDENT.STUDENT_ID
HAVING COUNT (STUDENT.STUDENT_ID) >4;
```

but nothing seems to work. Any help is appreciated. I am on SQL*Plus if that helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT EMPLOYER, COUNT (STUDENT_ID)
FROM STUDENT
GROUP BY EMPLOYER
HAVING COUNT (STUDENT_ID) >4;
```

- this will return a list of all employers with more than 4 students.

When grouping or including aggregated fields, your select statement should **only** include fields that are either aggregated or included in the `group by` clause - in your existing select, you are including `EMPLOYER` in your select clause, but not grouping by it or aggregating it.

Comment: thank you kind sir! I will try to remember this in the future.